# WPA_supplicants connection issues

Tags: wireless

Im trying to connect to my Wireless router but not having any luck.
Could someone give me a few pointers?

```
skay@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplica/wpa_supplicant.conf
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='Cerberus' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=0
```

This is my wpa_supplicants config:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
ap_scan=1 


network={
    ssid="Cerberus"
    #psk="XXXXXX"
    psk=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Inside the file add the following for **WPA2**

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
        ssid="ESSID_IN_QUOTES"
        psk="ASCII PSK Password in Quotes"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=RSN WPA
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

My Example : `ssid="A-B-C-D"`  & Password is  = `psk="abc12345"`

Then Remove **network-manager-gnome**

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome
```

#### Setting the Wireless Interface to Connect at Boot

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following lines

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig wlan0 down
dhclient -r wlan0
iwconfig wlan0 essid "A-B-C-D"
iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
ifconfig wlan0 up
dhclient wlan0
```

Then restart networking... I did a reboot

Note: I have already configured my router for **Static IP (Reserved IP from Router) &  DNS**

For more help see [this post on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188)

Comment: Hi Insafian, thanks for the answer, Can you explain me this "ASCII PSK Password in Quotes" from the file /etc/wpa_supplicant.. Do I need wpa_passphrase of my network here?

Comment: Didn't understand ...